# Proving a Laguerre polynomial integral

Tags: integration, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

After a fair bit of effort, I managed to prove that

$$\int_0^\infty t^\alpha \exp(-t) L_n^{\alpha+1}(t)\mathrm dt=\Gamma(\alpha+1)$$

where $L_n^\alpha (t)$ is a [generalized Laguerre polynomial](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.3), with the usual restriction of $\Re \alpha > -1$. My proof was rather complicated (involving lots of integration by parts); I'm wondering if there may be a simpler way of proving this proposition.

Answer (score 8):

Here, it is useful to know the [generating function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html) ($|z|<1$)
$$ \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{xz}{1-z}\right)}{(1-z)^{\alpha+1}} 
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty L^\alpha_n (x) z^n .$$ Thereby, we can evaluate the integral for all $n$ simultaneously
$$g=\sum_n z^n \int_0^\infty dt\, t^\alpha e^{-t} L_n^{\alpha+1}(t) 
 =  \int_0^\infty dt\, t^\alpha e^{-t}  \frac{\exp\left(-\frac{tz}{1-z}\right)}{(1-z)^{\alpha+2}}. $$
The integral can be brought onto the integral for the $\Gamma$ function by a change of variables
$$(1-z)^{\alpha+2} g= \int_0^\infty dt\, t^\alpha e^{ - \frac{t}{1-z} }
 = (1-z)^{\alpha+1} \int_0^\infty dt \, t^\alpha e^{ -t} 
=(1-z)^{\alpha+1} \Gamma(\alpha+1). $$
Thus, we have $g = \Gamma(\alpha+1)/(1-z)$ and
$$\int_0^\infty dt\, t^\alpha e^{-t} L_n^{\alpha+1}(t)  = \Gamma(\alpha+1) \qquad \forall n.$$

Answer (score 0):

How about using the recurrence relation for generalized Laguerre polynomials?